# YouTube iframe not appearing properly in OSX Firefox

Tags: firefox, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I'm building an application which plays videos using the YouTube iframe API. [You can see the application here.](http://ffsplayer.herokuapp.com/shows/384-matt-cardle-union-chapel-london-2-5-2013)

I've run into a weird issue where the player works ok in Chrome/Safari but won't show the video correctly in Firefox (I'm using FF22 on OSX 10.7.5). You can click the play button and hear the sound but the video never appears.

Anyone got any ideas what might be wrong?

**Some Observations**

You can see the YouTube branding (which is part of the player) so it's there, it's just not showing any picture.

According to @ceasar in the answers, the player works on Win 7 FF22. I have another report which states that it also works fine on Ubuntu FF.

If I open up the FF developer console and click various nodes in the DOM tree of that window, the video will appear. Try clicking `div.show-details` to see this effect (It's under `body > div.wide > div.show-details` )

There is a transparent overlay over the video but I'm setting `?wmode=opaque` on my iframe ([like this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3820325/574190)) so that should be ok.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9824082/574190) suggests that setting certain styling rules such as `border-radius` on the iframe can mess with it. I'm not doing anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

In FF the youtube logo isn't showing but working okay (win7 FF 22). Also in the other browsers I cannot click on the youtube logo. This is against the youtube TOS and you could be banned for this so be warned

Comment: I have [`modestbranding=1`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding) set in my iframe params so the YT logo only shows when then player is paused and hovered. I can fix the click-ability issue at a later date, this app is not technically in production yet. Thanks for the debugging info.