# Why does isotope mess up clicks into an iFrame?

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, jquery-isotope

So I'm doing a little hack to display a still image on top of an embedded YouTube video (which YouTube gives me as an iFrame). The idea is that the user will click the static image (a big colored box in the demo above) and then I use jQuery to hide the image and drop the iFrame where it was. I set the video to autoplay and boom, it starts playing.

The code is simple, it's several of these video blocks:

```
<div class='videoblock yellow'>
    <div data-videoid="7ZLywQpPgcA" class='overlay'>Click this text to play</div>
    <div class="thevideo"></div>
</div>
```

And then the code to init isotope, and the event handler to swap in the YouTube video on click:

```
$(function() {
    $('#iso').isotope({ itemSelector : '.videoblock' });   
});

// when the user clicks, hide the overlay, put the html code in for the iFrame and show it
$('.overlay').click(function() {
    vid = $(this).data('videoid');
    h = '<iframe width="435" height="265" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'+vid+'?autoplay=1" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $(this).hide(); $(this).next().show().html(h);
});
```

**jsfiddle live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pnoeric/MeL7a/7/**

The problem is that this technique works great in Chrome (Mac) and Safari, but in Firefox, the clicks don't have any effect on the video in YouTube. The pause button doesn't work, even though YouTube can see me hovering over the button.

Why is this? And how can I fix it? :-)

(I'm also open to any better technique to display a still image on top of a YouTube video...)

Comment: [Duopixel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747443/css-transform-translate-breaking-youtube-embedded-video?answertab=votes#tab-top) has a solution by adding `&html5=1` to the YouTube embed URL. [Firefox supports HTML5 video](http://caniuse.com/video) back to version 3.5 so it should be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isotope` uses `transform: translate(0px, 0px);` (in your case) on the `.videoblock` elements. This in turn triggers [Bug 832929 - "Can't interact with iframe flash content when parent node has CSS transforms applied"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=832929).

If possible, disable transforms via `options.transformsEnabled`.

Doing so in http://jsfiddle.net/nmaier/CkFWV/ makes it work in Firefox (Nightly on OSX, actually) for me.

Comment: You're a genius. Disabling transforms solved the problem. Thanks.